# c# How to copy text from a Website (not source code)

Tags: javascript, c#, string, copy

I want to copy the ZAR/BTC exchange rate from Luno.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String downloadedString = client.DownloadString("https://www.luno.com/en/price");
Console.WriteLine(downloadedString);
```

this is the code I am using but the string contains the entire page source, which is not the problem itself. The problem is where there should be the price for BTC in ZAR there is a javascript function called "FormatPrice()" instead of a price.

But I can simply highlight the price on the actual website and copy and paste. Is there any way for me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use their api? https://www.luno.com/en/api

Comment: I'm trying to find out how now, any tips on how on earth I do that?

Comment: You could use your existing code with the api's URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, you can't: downloading a site's HTML content does not actually perform all Javascript changes that modify its UI and data.

Please note that the site you are targeting [has an API you can use](https://www.luno.com/en/api) to get their data. That is the proper way of doing what you need.

Comment: Ohmygod API is exactly what I need. Thanks